# How to display just the limited part of data in Chart.Js?

Tags: chart.js

I have read the Chart.Js documentation but I didn't find any solution for my problem. In my Chart.Js I am trying to display only limited part of data. I mean I have data with a certain date interval (e.g. 2017.05.01-2017.05.20.) but I want to show just a part of this date interval (e.g. 2017.05.17 - 2017.05.20).  Is there any solution for his problem?